# ctx.message.guild returning None in server discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

No idea why this is happening, and I'm in desperate need of help.
Here's my code:

```
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def getserverid(self, ctx):
            print(ctx.message.guild.id)
```

I keep getting the error, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'"

And when trying to run this:

```
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def getserverid(self, ctx):
            print(ctx.message.guild)
```

It prints "None"

I'm testing this bot in a server and I'm out of ideas.

Anyone have any clue on how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a DM/PM?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out on my own. I had to enable guild intents, therefore needed to add this to my code

```
intents = discord.Intents(guilds = True)
```

Comment: Do press the 'check' button beneath the upvote/downvote buttons to mark this as your answer, thanks!

Comment: @Bagle Btw they can't accept their own answer until 48 hours has passed.

Comment: @Taku ah my mistake, completely forgot about that rule. Thanks for reminding me 

Answer (score -1):

```
@comamnds.Command()
async def getserverid(self, ctx:commands.Context):
    print(ctx.guild.id)
```